# Spring Data when does it connect to the database

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have been researching Spring Data Rest especially for cassandra and one of the questions my coworkers and I had was when does Spring Data connect to the database. We don't always want a rest controller to connect to the database so when does spring establish a connection if say we had a class extend the CRUDRepository? Does it connect to the database during the start of application itself? Is that something we can control?

For example, I implemented this example on Spring's website:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

At what point in the code does spring connect to the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring will connect to the DB as soon as the Datasource get initialized. Basically, Spring contexts will become alive somehow (Web listeners, manually calling them) and start creating beans. As soon as it reaches the Datasource, connection will be made and the connection pool will be populated.

Of course the above is based on a normal out of the box configuration and everything can be setup up to your taste.

So unless, you decide to control the connections yourself, DB connections will be sitting there waiting to be used.

Comment: So how can I control those connections? By not defining the datasource in the datasource file and connecting only when I want to access the database?

Comment: There are quite a few ways to do it really. One way could be you define your own Datasource so don't open connections until it's required. Or you could open the connections but only make them available to the component when needed so connections would be opened and living somewhere but not available. It really depends on your requirements.

Comment: Can you point me to any online documentation/guides that can walk me through that?

Comment: Sorry, I looked around but didn't find a "recipe" that shows how to implement your custom Datasource. You can start looking at the source code for https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/ for example and go from there. May I ask why you're so "concerned" about keeping Db connections open? Opening connections is one of the most costly things you can do in a DB hence the number of options for conenction pools and Datasources. Implementing your own is not a trivial thing and I could suggest you to start with one out of the box and make changes on the go. :)

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. Well my coworkers don't want to connect to the database from a controller if the controller doesn't need to. I haven't personally seen the issue they are facing but we are trying to move away from grails and move to Spring and they just wanted to know what the difference was and how much control they would get

Comment: Your Java apps will look a bit different from a Grails app. Usually the Java/Spring apps will be layered so your controllers don't have any knowledge of database, that would be down the data access layer. It would be something like this http://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/understanding-spring-web-application-architecture-the-classic-way/

Comment: I guess the question was really about connections from the connection pool. Apparently the controller was assigned a connection even if they didn't need it by grails. They just wanted to know if that would happen in Spring.

Answer (score -1):

Disagree with the above answer.
As part of research i initiated the datasource using a bean configuration and then changed my database password(not in my spring application but the real db username password)
The connection stays for a while and then in some point of time (maybe idle time) it stops working and throws credential exception.
This is enough to say the JPA does not keep the connection sitting and waiting to be used but uses some mechanism to occupy/release the db connection as per the need.

Comment: When you say it takes some time I am sure that it has some caching time or time to keep alive a thread. It definitely won't start throwing exception for each thread that is connected the moment you change password. It eventually changes as pool refreshes or unless there is an explicit DB call

Comment: Even DB calls work for a while, and after some time of inactivity, the connection just goes off. Please check it yourself first.

Comment: this is what I said. After some inactivity. Your answer is based on after the application has started, however the first answer is about initialisation. After some time, it refreshes, depending on your config. It actively tries to make connection with DB.